# Application crash on GT-N7100, android 4.4.2 because of resource mess up

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-resources

I have an application with google services, fragments etc. It is a gradle project
Debug version runs normally from android studio on GT-N7100 and other devices.
Resease version generated with command line runs OK on various devices, but crashes on GT-N7100 with Null Pointer Exception when using inflated layout.
GT-N7100 has rooted stock firmware, android 4.4.2

Code in Fragment inherited from android.app.Fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Context context = inflater.getContext();
    mRoot = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ecg_detection, container, false);
    mRoot.findViewById(R.id.deviceConnectedBtn).setOnClickListener(this);
    mRoot.findViewById(R.id.instructionsBtn).setOnClickListener(this);
    .......
    return mRoot;
}
```

It throws NullPointerException on line

```
mRoot.findViewById(R.id.deviceConnectedBtn).setOnClickListener(this);
```

Resource R.layout.fragment_ecg_detection declared only once:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_instruction"
    tools:context="ru.nordavind.ecgdongle.fragment.StickDetectionFragment">

    ....

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_white"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/instructionsBtn"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/deviceConnectedBtn"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/instructions"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward_600"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    ....

</RelativeLayout>
```

gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 47
        versionName "1.2." + versionCode
    }
    applicationVariants.matching(
            { it.buildType.name == android.buildTypes.release.name }
    ).all { variant ->
        def flavor = variant.productFlavors.get(0)
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.outputFile = new File(
                    output.outputFile.parent,
                    "${flavor.name}-release-${variant.versionName}.apk")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    signingConfigs {
        releaseConfig {
            storeFile file("...")
            storePassword "..."
            keyAlias "..."
            keyPassword "..."
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
            /*
            due to bug
                https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=733
             */
            lintOptions { disable 'MissingTranslation' }
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
        }
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
    productFlavors {
        ...
        EcgDongle {
            applicationId '.....'
            versionCode 41
            versionName "1." + (versionCode - 34) + ".2"

            copy {
                from "src/EcgDongle"
                include "google-services.json"
                into "."
            }
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
    testCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-rc3') {
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    }

    compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.1.6@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
    compile 'com.opencsv:opencsv:3.6'
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.6.1'
}
```

exception:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {ru.nordavind.ecgdongle/ru.nordavind.ecgdongle.MainActivityEcgStick}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3076)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3105)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ru.nordavind.ecgdongle.fragment.StickDetectionFragment.onCreateView(StickDetectionFragment.java:56)
 at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
 at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1453)
 at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5541)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3066)
 ... 12 more
```

also, before that I get messages:

```
06-23 16:50:27.266 I/dalvikvm(30277): Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzi
06-23 16:50:27.266 W/dalvikvm(30277): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 588: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
06-23 16:50:27.266 D/dalvikvm(30277): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
06-23 16:50:27.311 I/GMPM (30277): App measurement is starting up, version: 8487
06-23 16:50:27.311 I/GMPM (30277): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.GMPM VERBOSE
06-23 16:50:27.336 E/GMPM (30277): GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services. Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
06-23 16:50:27.336 E/GMPM (30277): Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
06-23 16:50:27.391 E/GMPM (30277): Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
06-23 16:50:27.681 W/dalvikvm(30277): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/os/PersistableBundle;)
06-23 16:50:27.681 I/dalvikvm(30277): Could not find method android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onRestoreInstanceState, referenced from method ru.nordavind.ecgdongle.MainActivityEcgStick.onRestoreInstanceState
06-23 16:50:27.681 W/dalvikvm(30277): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11841: Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity;.onRestoreInstanceState (Landroid/os/Bundle;Landroid/os/PersistableBundle;)V
06-23 16:50:27.681 D/dalvikvm(30277): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
06-23 16:50:27.751 W/dalvikvm(30277): No implementation found for native Ldalvik/system/VMRuntime;.pauseGc:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
06-23 16:50:27.751 E/ActivityThread(30277): Pause GC
06-23 16:50:27.751 E/ActivityThread(30277): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-23 16:50:27.751 E/ActivityThread(30277): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 16:50:27.751 E/ActivityThread(30277): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-23 16:50:27.751 E/ActivityThread(30277): at android.app.ActivityThread.pauseGC(ActivityThread.java:5525)
06-23 16:50:27.751 E/ActivityThread(30277): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2324)
06-23 16:50:27.751 E/ActivityThread(30277): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
06-23 16:50:27.751 E/ActivityThread(30277): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
06-23 16:50:27.751 E/ActivityThread(30277): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
06-23 16:50:27.751 E/ActivityThread(30277): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-23 16:50:27.751 E/ActivityThread(30277): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
06-23 16:50:27.751 E/ActivityThread(30277): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
06-23 16:50:27.751 E/ActivityThread(30277): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 16:50:27.751 E/ActivityThread(30277): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-23 16:50:27.751 E/ActivityThread(30277): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
06-23 16:50:27.751 E/ActivityThread(30277): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
06-23 16:50:27.751 E/ActivityThread(30277): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-23 16:50:27.751 E/ActivityThread(30277): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: dalvik.system.VMRuntime.pauseGc:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
06-23 16:50:27.751 E/ActivityThread(30277): at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.pauseGc(Native Method)
06-23 16:50:27.751 E/ActivityThread(30277): ... 15 more
06-23 16:50:27.786 D/dalvikvm(30277): GC_CONCURRENT freed 310K, 14% free 8086K/9368K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 21ms
06-23 16:50:27.906 I/dalvikvm(30277): Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
06-23 16:50:27.906 W/dalvikvm(30277): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 666: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
06-23 16:50:27.906 D/dalvikvm(30277): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
06-23 16:50:27.906 I/dalvikvm(30277): Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
06-23 16:50:27.906 W/dalvikvm(30277): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 688: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
06-23 16:50:27.906 D/dalvikvm(30277): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
06-23 16:50:27.931 D/dalvikvm(30277): GC_CONCURRENT freed 384K, 15% free 8138K/9496K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 22ms
```

including

```
GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services. Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
```

It looks it messed up with resources.
What to do with it?

Comment: did you add the proguard rules in your proguard-file?

Comment: @Martin-Pfeffer, minify is not enabled

Comment: ok, and what about your google-services.json file? did you nest it to the modules root directory? https://i.imgur.com/KeB9TYK.png

Comment: @Martin-Pfeffer yes, it is nested and it is copied with script in flavor options. It is ok on other devices, but failed on GT-N7100